# Installing IIS URL Rewrite via .msi doesn't create appropriate sectionGroup

Tags: iis, ansible

I am installing [URL rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) with Ansible's [`win_package`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_package_module.html) by giving `path` as [the MSI installer](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi).

Subsequently I get `HTTP Error 500.19` for all requests.

This seems to occur due to because I am missing `<sectionGroup name="rewrite">` in `applicationHost.config`.

Given that URL rewrite **requires** this `sectionGroup`, why isn't it added by the installer? Am I missing something?

---

Here is the `sectionGroup` declaration which resolves the issue:

```
<sectionGroup name="rewrite">
    <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="outboundRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="providers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="allowedServerVariables" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sectionGroup` is added by the link MSI installer on first install. However if it is inadvertently removed then neither IIS Manager nor a 'repair' install will put it back.

The MSI must be **fully uninstalled and then reinstalled**.

Comment: Glad you got this solved!